# Количество, сумма элементов и наибольший элемент

Tags: массивы, pascal, циклы

1. В заданной последовательности целых чисел определить количество и сумму элементов, кратных числу 10.
2. В заданном массиве заменить нулём наибольший элемент

Во второй задаче понимаю только, как узнать наибольший элемент, а как заменить его нулём, не знаю. В 1 не понимаю условия.

Comment: 2 задача решается значительно проще, если искать не значение максимального элемента, а его индекс. В таком случае заменить нулем будет очень просто.

в 1 задаче, нужно не просто суммировать, а перед суммированием проверять, где то так `if (a[i] mod 10 = 0) then begin s := s+a[i]; n := n + 1; end;` Цикл думаю уже добавите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Условие простое. Скажем, есть последовательность {1,2,3,10,25,4,99,25,90,33}. Тогда мы выбираем числа 10 и 90 и считаем их сумму. Условие делимости - `a[i] mod 10 = 0`
2. Ищете максимальный элемент, сохраняете его индекс и потом заменяете этот элемент нулем.

Comment: как же это написать?

Comment: в моем коментарии есть пол ответа (пол кода). Или Вам нужно полное решение?

Comment: и вообще, давать полный ответ на учебные задания -- зло.